# Change label BackColor in visualbasic

Tags: vb.net, label, backcolor

I'm working on an Epicor customization made on VB and I'm having problems changing a label backcolor. I want to change it to red, for example, depending on an event but it does nothing. The code I'm using is just like this..

label.BackColor = Color.Red

Any ideas? Am I missing something or is there any other way to change color? I've already tried with Color.FromRGB method but doesn't work.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's how you do it, are you sure that code is getting executed? Debug it...

Comment: @DonA All the other functionality is working without problems. I can change the label text, size, position, but can't change backcolor.

Comment: WHERE that code is might make a difference ie "are you sure that code is getting executed?"

Comment: try to refresh the form

Comment: are you later changing the backcolor to its original state?